# Normal Approximation to the Binomial (Multiple Choice Question)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

[image]

My first instinct in this question is use Normal approximation because N is large, and P is exactly between 1 and 0. I used the normal approximation, calculated when $p(X\le 19)$ and got 0.8997. The correct answer.

The confusion arrives at the highlighted part. In my head, wouldn't atleast one would mean $1-p(X=0)=P(X\geq 1)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted "at least one credit card" corresponds to the "at least one credit card" on lines 1-2.

And the $X$ you have been using is the number of persons, not number of cards.

Comment: Suppose in a separate question, which is duplicate of the question above^, has instead of "atleast one credit card" but "atleast 3 credit cards" how would one solve that? You don't need to solve but tell me how you would.

Comment: One could go way out on a limb and assume that the number of credit cards held by an individual has Poisson distribution. It is more reasonable to say that there is not enough information even to approximate the number with at least three.